# Different result from App.Model.find() and App.Model.find({params})

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a todo-app (original, right?) and have a problem that ember doesn't display my newly created objects if use find({some parameters}) instead of find().

The problem seems to be that App.Model.find() returns a different result than, for example,  App.Model.find({checked: false}).

I've created TasksRoute and defined the model data as App.Task.find().
When using App.Task.find() I can create a new task by typing:

```
var task = App.Task.createRecord({name: "taskName"});
task.get("store").commit();
```

The list is updated and the view displays the newly created task.

But if I instead use App.Model.find({}), or with any other hash, and then create a task nothing happens.

Here's the html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{#linkTo "tasks"}}Tasks{{/linkTo}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tasks">
  {{#each controller}}
    {{name}}<br />
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
App = Em.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({url: "http://localhost/backend/"})
});

App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
})

App.TasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Task.find();
    }
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('tasks');
});

App.TasksController = Em.ArrayController.extend({});
```

The reason that I don't want to use find() is that I want to be able to specify my query. For example I would like to be able to retrieve all tasks that are checked by providing a hash to find().

(I tried creating a jsFiddle but didn't manage to get it to work with fixtures)

Is this a bug or have I done something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `filterProperty('checked', false)` instead of `find({params})`

Comment: It would be a good idea if it weren't for the fact that I can only use filterProperty when the data is already loaded. In my case there can be hundreds of tasks in total, and to decrease load time I want to limit that amount.